# macos SystemExtension install

Tags: macos

I am developing on MacOS and have completed development after referencing SystemExtension and NetworkExtension, and I want to install it for distribution.

Also, the structure is shown below.

========================================================================

Applications

------------Group 1 (Type: Application Bundle) , (Framework: NetworkExtension, SystemExtension) , (Embedded Content: Group2 (embed without signing)

------------Group 2 (Type: Plug-in) , (Framework: AppKit, DiskArbiration,NetworkExtension) ,                                (Lib: libbsm.tbd , libEndpointSecurity.tbd

========================================================================

Moved the built app to the PC being distributed.
(Delivered signed app by drag and drop without registering in APP Store)

But currently I am having the following problem:

When SIP is released and installed, network communication works normally. However, after enabling SIP, it is installed, but the network is not always connected (Starting is displayed in the network setting).

I'm new to Xcode and it's my first project, so I don't know where to go further.

Comment: The endpoint-security permission must be assigned after making a direct request to apple.
Therefore, it was solved after creating a provisioning profile after being assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint-security permission must be assigned after making a direct request to apple.
Therefore, it was solved after creating a provisioning profile after being assigned.